# Open file created by R in an external program

Tags: r, shell, logging

I want R to open a file that is created in my program. My code saves a log file to a variable called logFile using the following code.

```
logFile <- sprintf("../output/%s_%s_output%sof%s.log", str1, str2, str3, str4);
```

I tried to access the shell function by calling

```
shell('%s',logFile);
```

but I got an error that said

```
In shell("%s", toFile) : '%s' execution failed with error code 127
```

How can I get my program to open this file after it is finished writing to it?

Comment: What is the `shell` function in R? I haven't heard of it and can't find any documentation.

Comment: @DavidRobinson http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/shell

Comment: @user1876508 Why not just use native R functions like `write` and `read.table` or `readLines` to read?

Comment: I want to actually open the file, with a text editor such as notepad. This would be the final output once the code finishes executing

Comment: Why do you think that your shell invocation would do that?

Comment: You can use the `system` function to run a command on the command line. What operating system are you using?

Comment: ...as opposed to file.edit() for instance?

Comment: Also, I think your computer is as baffled as I am as to why you would want your log file to execute the command %s.

Comment: I am using windows. I have tried using system('logFile'); and system("../output/%s_%s_output%sof%s.log", str1, str2, str3, str4); but neither give me the intended results, only an error.

Answer (score 11):

How about?

```
browseURL('view.xlsx')
```

Comment: Adding a bit of explanation to answers like this one will help avoid having your answer automatically flagged for low quality because of length.

Answer (score 9):

Are you looking for something like this? It works nicely, at least on my Windows box.

```
## An example temp file
ff <- paste0(tempfile(), ".txt")
write.table(head(mtcars), file=ff)

## Open the file with the program associated with its file extension
system2("open", ff)
```

Answer (score 0):

For an solution that naturally extends your attempts, you could use shell.exec.

[Documentation](https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/datasets/R/html/base/html/shell.exec.html)

Opens the specified file using the application specified in the Windows file associations.

```r
ff <- paste0(tempfile(), ".txt")
write.table(head(mtcars), file=ff)

shell.exec(ff)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>